using tokens when including files
I'm trying to use include along with the token
premake5:
include "%{wks.location}/BuildSystemDependencies/UNIX/MacOS/Dependencies.lua"

file tree:
├── BuildSystemDependencies
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── build
├── premake5.lua

my premake5, which is next to the folder
BuildSystemDependencies
contains a workspace for defining the wks.location token
workspace "Radiant"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
    architecture "x64"
    startproject "Sanxbox"

    language "C++"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    targetdir "build/Bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}"
    objdir "build/Intermediates/%{cfg.buildcfg}"

    externalanglebrackets "On"
    externalwarnings "Off"
    warnings "Off"


group "ThirdParty"
include "ThirdParty/"
group ""

-- Platform-specific includes
if os.target() == "windows" then
    include "Radiant/BuildSystem/Windows"
elseif os.target() == "macosx" then
    include "Radiant/BuildSystem/UNIX/MacOS"
end

But I get an error
Error: unable to open %{wks.location}/BuildSystemDependencies/Dependencies.lua: No such file or directory
What's the reason my wks.location is not detected?

Tokens are mostly handled for "properties", there are several places where there are not handled (filter and as you discover include).
